# Get last reading data and add to next row Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Sorry if this is a simple one but I have spent days on it!

I have a system built in CakePHP version 2.2.4 that allows a user to input a meter reading via a simple form. The form asks for:

1. Reading Date
2. Previous Reading
3. Current Reading
4. Average flow  (Worked out by: Current Reading - Previous Reading = x divisible by total days since last reading = Average Flow

I am trying to get the /add.ctp to automatically pull in the previous reading and work out the Average flow as above.

I need as much help as you can possibly give guys!

Comment: Do the blog tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html#build-a-blog it covers that.

Comment: Hi @burzum, I have done that tutorial previously. I have the system built and know how to build a form etc. My question was how do I pull the last reading in to a new reading as as the previous reading and how do I do the code to work out the average flow.

Comment: $this->request->data = $this->Model->getById($previousId);

Comment: Hi @burzum, thanks for your help! I am still not understanding what that code does or where I am supposed to put it? Can you explain a little more please?